# user authentication package

Tags: java, authentication

I need a quick and dirty way to authenticate user(GUI is also included) in java web start app, how/where can I find one?  
if I need to make it a webapp (war file), that's fine too.

Answer (score 0):

In which approach do you want to authenticate the user? Local authentication or third-party based authentication? Don't known any utilizable library for local authentication. However, [openID](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/) or [oAuth](http://oauth.net/code/) can be employed if you want trusty service provider help you complete.

Comment: I want local authentication preferably basic http authentication.